# How to open an existing azure function in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, azure-functions

I'm pretty new to Azure and using the portal, wrote an Azure Function. Now I would like to continue working on it using Visual Studio 2017. I can't seem to find a way to open/edit this existing function in Visual Studio though.

I'm sure I could create a new Azure Function in VS, copy code over, setup/connect to storage, etc. and deploy a new instance and delete the current instance, but would like to avoid that.

Ideally, was hoping there was some kind of open/connect to Azure account in VS, or maybe an "edit in VS" button in the portal, etc.

TIA!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, as close as you can get to that is to go to the portal, your Function App, then click `Download app content` button and ask for Visual Studio solution:

[image: Download app content]

[image: With Visual studio project]

This will give you a zip file with Functions, including `csproj` file.

The problem is that portal functions are C# scripts (`csx` files), and Visual Studio isn't great to work with them. When you create a new Function App in Visual Studio 2017, it will make a *precompiled* function project - a normal class library with `cs` files.

Unfortunately, there is no automated way to convert script functions to precompiled ones.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!