# How to download an azure function from azure platform to a local function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, serverless

I've made some changes to my azure function from the Azure platform and now I want to update my local serverless app function, how can I do that? 
I know that if I want to do the reverse I just have to deploy the function using this command "serverless deploy function -f function-name" but what if I want to do the reverse which command can I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a similar question from a couple years ago here:
[How to open an existing azure function in visual studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47490710/how-to-open-an-existing-azure-function-in-visual-studio)

You can download the hosted function as a zip file which includes a visual studio project file.

I don't know of a way to update your existing local project besides downloading and copying and pasting the files into your existing local directory.

Hope that helps!